# Parsing error after updating dependencies

Tags: reactjs, typescript, package.json

I was updating some packages in my React Project and I needed to update the typescript version, the problem is that I started receiving the following error

`Parsing error: DeprecationError: 'originalKeywordKind' has been deprecated since v5.0.0 and can no longer be used. Use 'identifierToKeywordKind(identifier)' instead`

This is my package.json

```
  "name": "some_name_here",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.5.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-components": "^2.6.34",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.11.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.0",
    "@hedgedoc/html-to-react": "^1.4.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/esri-leaflet-geocoder": "^2.2.3",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@unform/core": "^2.1.3",
    "@unform/web": "^2.1.3",
    "antd": "^5.10.2",
    "antd-img-crop": "^4.13.0",
    "antd-mask-input": "^0.1.15",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "cep-promise": "^4.1.0",
    "cpf-cnpj-validator": "^1.0.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.24.0",
    "esri-leaflet": "^3.0.8",
    "esri-leaflet-geocoder": "^3.1.3",
    "faker": "^5.5.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "gerador-validador-cpf": "^5.0.2",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.9.2",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "leaflet-control-geocoder": "^2.4.0",
    "leaflet-geosearch": "^3.3.2",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",
    "miragejs": "^0.1.41",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.4",
    "polished": "^4.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.17.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-countdown-circle-timer": "^3.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-highlight-words": "^0.17.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.2.0",
    "react-leaflet-cluster": "^1.0.3",
    "react-leaflet-markercluster": "^3.0.0-rc1",
    "react-number-format": "^4.7.3",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.1.47",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-query": "^3.19.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.3",
    "react-video-js-player": "^1.1.1",
    "simple-react-lightbox": "^3.6.9-0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/pages/**/*.tsx",
      "src/components/**/*.tsx",
      "src/hooks/*.tsx",
      "!src/hooks/index.tsx"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "~(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/faker": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/i18n-js": "^3.8.2",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.7.3",
    "@types/pdfmake": "^0.1.20",
    "@types/react-color": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/react-highlight-words": "^0.16.3",
    "@types/react-infinite-scroll-component": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/react-leaflet-markercluster": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/simple-react-lightbox": "^3.6.1",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.6.0",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "docz": "^2.3.1",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.12.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-plugin-root-import": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^1.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1"
  }
}
```

I've already tried updating `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and I couldn't solve the problem. This problem started happening after I updated antd and typescript to newer versions.

Comment: What's the full stack of the error? It's impossible to guess from what dependency the error comes from just with what you shared.

Comment: That's the problem, this is the full error.

Comment: The error is from TypeScript so one of your dependency is not compatible with the version you now use. Either downgrade or update your dependencies one by one and see if it fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe this? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13286#issuecomment-1764885809

Comment: I tried this solution but unfortunately it didn't work, I'll try to downgrade the dependencies one by one to see if it works.

Comment: I meant downgrade TypeScript, not your other dependencies, the function [`identifierToKeywordKind`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3e12250839fae5054b7cedac25124da5be928066/src/compiler/utilitiesPublic.ts#L798) is from TS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple dependency issues you have in your package.json.

## `react-scripts`

The most likely culprit of the error is that `react-scripts` relies on typescript being either v3 or v4, and does not have v5 support.

> This can be fixed by ejecting your app (though you should do a backup beforehand)

## `docz`

The second most likely candidate is that `docz` also only supports v3 and v4.

> `docz` can just be upgraded to the latest version.

## `@ant-design/pro-components`

The least likely, but probably annoying issue is that `@ant-design/pro-components` only supports `react` v17 and above.

> This can be fixed by either upgrading `react` or downgrading `@ant-design/pro-components`

These were the main issues I found using `npm ls typescript`, which outputs all packages that have a peer/dev/optional/regular dependency on `typescript`, you may want to check `npm ls @typescript-eslint/parser` and `npm ls @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`

Comment: Thank you very much to you and others who tried to help me, I updated React, Docz and react-scripts and my problem was solved.